# SQL Syntax Failure - Experienced SQL Eyes Needed

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a piece of software that provides SQL data from the backend of an old Linux server we use in the business.

Every now and then we have to do a 'BULK INSERT' of this data into our SQL, what this does is DROPS the relevant tables and anything attached (Triggers etc.) and rebuilds them and repopulates the data.

The software provides a Pre-SQL and Post-SQL 'Scripting' area where you can place your own scripts. I would like to place a script in there however it always fails with a syntax issue.

I literally copy and paste below:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[Tr_icp_Dapolicy_Insert] 
ON  [dbo].[icp_Dapolicy] 
AFTER INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO T_FIG_PreDialler (Branch@, Key@, PolicyRef@, ClientRef@, Create_Date, Create_Time, Copied, CopyDateTime) 
        SELECT 
            Branch@, Key@, PolicyRef@, ClientRef@, Create_date, Create_time, 0, GETDATE() 
        FROM 
            INSERTED
        WHERE 
            Branch@ <>1
END

CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[Tr_icp_Dapolicy_Update] 
ON  [dbo].[icp_Dapolicy] 
AFTER UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    IF UPDATE(#Exec)
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO T_FIG_PreDiallerUpdates (Branch@, Key@, NewExec, OldExec) 
            SELECT 
                INSERTED.Branch@, INSERTED.Key@, INSERTED.#Exec, DELETED.#Exec 
            FROM 
                INSERTED
            INNER JOIN 
                DELETED ON INSERTED.Branch@ = DELETED.Branch@
                        AND INSERTED.Key@ = DELETED.Key@
            WHERE 
                ((INSERTED.#Exec = ''9999'') AND (DELETED.#Exec <> ''9999'')) 
                OR ((INSERTED.#Exec <> ''9999'') AND (DELETED.#Exec = ''9999''))
                AND (INSERTED.Branch@ in (0, 2))
    END
END

CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[Tr_icp_brcledger_Insert] 
ON  [dbo].[icp_brcledger] 
AFTER INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO T_FIG_Trigger_Ledger_Add (Branch@, Key@, PolicyRef@, ClientRef@, [Suffix@],
                [Polref], [Poltype], [Suffix], [Trantype], [Dt_raised],[Status], [Ledger_dt], [Remarks_4], 
                [#Exec], [Datecreated], [Operator], [LastUpdatedTime])
        SELECT 
            Branch@, Key@, PolicyRef@, ClientRef@, [Suffix@], 
            [Polref], [Poltype], [Suffix], [Trantype], [Dt_raised], [Status], [Ledger_dt], [Remarks_4],
            [#Exec], [Datecreated], [Operator], [LastUpdatedTime]
        FROM 
            INSERTED
        WHERE 
            (INSERTED.Trantype IN (''New Business'', ''Renewal'', ''Transfrd NB''))
            OR ((INSERTED.Branch@ = 2) 
              AND (INSERTED.Poltype = ''LE'')
              AND (INSERTED.Trantype = ''Charge''))
END

CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[Tr_icp_brcledger_Update] 
ON  [dbo].[icp_brcledger] 
AFTER UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Now DateTime;
    SET @Now = GETDATE();

    INSERT INTO T_FIG_Trigger_Ledger_Update
              (Branch@, Key@, PolicyRef@_Before, Poltype_Before, Trantype_Before, Ledger_dt_Before, 
                    Remarks_4_Before, #Exec_Before, Datecreated_Before, Operator_Before, 
                    LastUpdatedTime_Before, PolicyRef@_After, Poltype_After, Trantype_After, Ledger_dt_After, 
                    Remarks_4_After, #Exec_After, Datecreated_After, Operator_After, 
                    LastUpdatedTime_After, Copied, CopyDateTime, 
                    Orig_debt_Before, Comm_amt_Before, Orig_debt_After, Comm_amt_After)
        SELECT 
            INSERTED.[Branch@], INSERTED.[Key@],
            DELETED.[PolicyRef@] AS [PolicyRef@_Before],
            DELETED.[Poltype] AS [Poltype_Before],
            DELETED.[Trantype] AS [Trantype@_Before],
            DELETED.[Ledger_dt] AS [Ledger_dt_Before],
            DELETED.[Remarks_4] AS [Remarks_4_Before],
            DELETED.[#Exec] AS [#Exec_Before],
            DELETED.[Datecreated] AS [Datecreated_Before],
            DELETED.[Operator] AS [Operator_Before],
            DELETED.[LastUpdatedTime] AS [LastUpdatedTime_Before],
            INSERTED.[PolicyRef@] AS [PolicyRef@_After],
            INSERTED.[Poltype]AS [Poltype_After],
            INSERTED.[Trantype]AS [Trantype@_After],
            INSERTED.[Ledger_dt] AS [Ledger_dt_After],
            INSERTED.[Remarks_4] AS [Remarks_4_After],
            INSERTED.[#Exec] AS [#Exec_After],
            INSERTED.[Datecreated] AS [Datecreated_After],
            INSERTED.[Operator] AS [Operator_After],
            INSERTED.[LastUpdatedTime] AS [LastUpdatedTime_After],
            0, @Now,
            DELETED.Orig_debt AS [Orig_debt_Before],
            DELETED.Comm_amt AS [Comm_amt_Before],
            INSERTED.Orig_debt AS [Orig_debt_After],
            INSERTED.Comm_amt AS [Comm_amt_After]
        FROM 
            DELETED 
        INNER JOIN 
            INSERTED ON DELETED.Branch@ = INSERTED.Branch@ AND DELETED.Key@ = INSERTED.Key@
        WHERE 
            (INSERTED.PolicyRef@ <> DELETED.PolicyRef@
            OR INSERTED.Poltype <> DELETED.Poltype
            OR INSERTED.Trantype <> DELETED.Trantype
            OR INSERTED.Ledger_dt  <> DELETED.Ledger_dt
            OR INSERTED.Ledger_dt is null and DELETED.Ledger_dt is not null
            OR INSERTED.Ledger_dt is not null and DELETED.Ledger_dt is null
            OR ISNULL(INSERTED.Remarks_4, ''NULL'') <> isnull(DELETED.Remarks_4, ''NULL'')
            OR ISNULL(INSERTED.#Exec, ''NULL'') <> isnull(DELETED.#Exec, ''NULL'')
            OR ISNULL(INSERTED.Operator, ''NULL'') <> isnull(DELETED.Operator, ''NULL'')
            OR INSERTED.Operator <> DELETED.Operator
            OR INSERTED.Orig_debt <> DELETED.Orig_debt
            OR INSERTED.Comm_amt <> DELETED.Comm_amt)
            AND (INSERTED.Trantype <> ''Journal'')
END

CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[Tr_icp_brcledger_Delete] 
ON  [dbo].[icp_brcledger] 
AFTER DELETE
AS 
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO T_FIG_Trigger_Ledger_Delete (Branch@, Key@,PolicyRef@, TranType, PolType)
        SELECT 
            Branch@, Key@,PolicyRef@, Trantype, Poltype
        FROM 
            DELETED
        WHERE 
            (DELETED.Trantype <> ''Journal'')
END
```

When it attempts to then run this at the end of the BULK INSERT I get errors like:

> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'TRIGGER'.

Now I'm not asking for help on the software, my question is this:

What syntax would exist for the above to fail? I can run this in a SQL Query Window and its successful, what have these software developers coded 'before' this postdone-sql script runs for it to cause a syntax error?

Thanks for any and all help about this, because the software vendor themselves have little to no clue and haven't been able to answer this for 2 years.

**UPDATE**

Attempted to wrap the whole thing in a var char and exec it and this also failed

```
 DECLARE @CreateTriggers VARCHAR(MAX);

    SET @CreateTriggers = 'CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[Tr_icp_Dapolicy_Insert] 
                       ON  [dbo].[icp_Dapolicy] 
                       AFTER INSERT
                    AS 
                    BEGIN
                                    INSERT INTO T_FIG_PreDialler (Branch@, Key@, PolicyRef@, ClientRef@, Create_Date, Create_Time, Copied, CopyDateTime) 
                                                    SELECT Branch@, Key@, PolicyRef@, ClientRef@, Create_date, Create_time, 0, GETDATE() FROM INSERTED
                                                    WHERE Branch@ <>1

                    END'

    EXEC(@CreateTriggers);
```

Comment: basic debugging: start eliminating trigger definitions to see if it's one in particular that's causing it, or perhaps the overall usage is wrong, even if the individual statements are incorrect.

Comment: Code seems fine at first glance - nothing glaringly obvious wrong with it. The only thing that kinda "smells" a little are the various `AND`  and `OR` conditions in your `WHERE` clauses - are you 150% sure those are correctly interpreted (seeing that `AND` has a higher precedence than `OR` )

Comment: @MarcB He says he can run the script OK in a SQL Query Window. Problem is the software is doing something odd behind the scenes I think.

Comment: @codeulike is bang on, the query above runs FINE in a SQL SSMS window. No issues at all. Only within the 'software' does this occur.

Comment: Your code uses double quotes `''` in strings, so there's no way that this works ok in SSMS. Might work if you assign something like this into a varchar + use Exec.

Comment: I can guarantee you this works in SSMS JamesZ, but yes I am attempting it assigned as a varchar and then using Exec, I'm testing the bulk insert procedure as we speak.

Comment: Really this is a 'my enterprisey software is doing something stupid' problem rather than a SQL syntax problem. #enterprisey

Answer (score 1):

It might be something to do with the software sending the statements via JDBC.

Or perhaps they are sending the pre/post scripts in a batch along with other stuff, so SQL Server complains because 'CREATE TRIGGER' must be first thing in a batch.

Other people with similar-ish problems have suggested the option of wrapping whole thing in an `exec(' ')` clause.

See [Create mssql trigger from java program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25638134/create-mssql-trigger-from-java-program)

and also this answer to another question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/951956/22194

Comment: Hi codeulike, I have actually toyed with this idea but I'm awaiting for a 'test' bulk insert to finish, I will try your theory tomorrow as I also have this 'lined' up as my next go to test.

Comment: I declare the variable, wrapped the whole create trigger script into the variable and then EXEC'd it and it give me the some error again :(

Comment: Hmm ok. You could try leaving the triggers in place (instead of DROP/CREATE) and using ENABLE TRIGGER and DISABLE TRIGGER commands https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182706.aspx .... alternatively I guess you give up on the software and try and find another way of running scripts before and after - some sort of automation or scripting from the next level up

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have a choice on giving up on the software, and the downside is it doesn't leave the triggers in place because they have coded the bulk insert to 'drop' the tables so it drops the triggers as well.

Answer (score 0):

This should work, you were just missing the GO statement after each CREATE statement. Each trigger creation script has to be within its own batch:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[Tr_icp_Dapolicy_Insert] 
ON  [dbo].[icp_Dapolicy] 
AFTER INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO T_FIG_PreDialler (Branch@, Key@, PolicyRef@, ClientRef@, Create_Date, Create_Time, Copied, CopyDateTime) 
        SELECT 
            Branch@, Key@, PolicyRef@, ClientRef@, Create_date, Create_time, 0, GETDATE() 
        FROM 
            INSERTED
        WHERE 
            Branch@ <>1
END
GO

CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[Tr_icp_Dapolicy_Update] 
ON  [dbo].[icp_Dapolicy] 
AFTER UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    IF UPDATE(#Exec)
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO T_FIG_PreDiallerUpdates (Branch@, Key@, NewExec, OldExec) 
            SELECT 
                INSERTED.Branch@, INSERTED.Key@, INSERTED.#Exec, DELETED.#Exec 
            FROM 
                INSERTED
            INNER JOIN 
                DELETED ON INSERTED.Branch@ = DELETED.Branch@
                        AND INSERTED.Key@ = DELETED.Key@
            WHERE 
                ((INSERTED.#Exec = ''9999'') AND (DELETED.#Exec <> ''9999'')) 
                OR ((INSERTED.#Exec <> ''9999'') AND (DELETED.#Exec = ''9999''))
                AND (INSERTED.Branch@ in (0, 2))
    END
END
GO

CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[Tr_icp_brcledger_Insert] 
ON  [dbo].[icp_brcledger] 
AFTER INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO T_FIG_Trigger_Ledger_Add (Branch@, Key@, PolicyRef@, ClientRef@, [Suffix@],
                [Polref], [Poltype], [Suffix], [Trantype], [Dt_raised],[Status], [Ledger_dt], [Remarks_4], 
                [#Exec], [Datecreated], [Operator], [LastUpdatedTime])
        SELECT 
            Branch@, Key@, PolicyRef@, ClientRef@, [Suffix@], 
            [Polref], [Poltype], [Suffix], [Trantype], [Dt_raised], [Status], [Ledger_dt], [Remarks_4],
            [#Exec], [Datecreated], [Operator], [LastUpdatedTime]
        FROM 
            INSERTED
        WHERE 
            (INSERTED.Trantype IN (''New Business'', ''Renewal'', ''Transfrd NB''))
            OR ((INSERTED.Branch@ = 2) 
              AND (INSERTED.Poltype = ''LE'')
              AND (INSERTED.Trantype = ''Charge''))
END
GO

CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[Tr_icp_brcledger_Update] 
ON  [dbo].[icp_brcledger] 
AFTER UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Now DateTime;
    SET @Now = GETDATE();

    INSERT INTO T_FIG_Trigger_Ledger_Update
              (Branch@, Key@, PolicyRef@_Before, Poltype_Before, Trantype_Before, Ledger_dt_Before, 
                    Remarks_4_Before, #Exec_Before, Datecreated_Before, Operator_Before, 
                    LastUpdatedTime_Before, PolicyRef@_After, Poltype_After, Trantype_After, Ledger_dt_After, 
                    Remarks_4_After, #Exec_After, Datecreated_After, Operator_After, 
                    LastUpdatedTime_After, Copied, CopyDateTime, 
                    Orig_debt_Before, Comm_amt_Before, Orig_debt_After, Comm_amt_After)
        SELECT 
            INSERTED.[Branch@], INSERTED.[Key@],
            DELETED.[PolicyRef@] AS [PolicyRef@_Before],
            DELETED.[Poltype] AS [Poltype_Before],
            DELETED.[Trantype] AS [Trantype@_Before],
            DELETED.[Ledger_dt] AS [Ledger_dt_Before],
            DELETED.[Remarks_4] AS [Remarks_4_Before],
            DELETED.[#Exec] AS [#Exec_Before],
            DELETED.[Datecreated] AS [Datecreated_Before],
            DELETED.[Operator] AS [Operator_Before],
            DELETED.[LastUpdatedTime] AS [LastUpdatedTime_Before],
            INSERTED.[PolicyRef@] AS [PolicyRef@_After],
            INSERTED.[Poltype]AS [Poltype_After],
            INSERTED.[Trantype]AS [Trantype@_After],
            INSERTED.[Ledger_dt] AS [Ledger_dt_After],
            INSERTED.[Remarks_4] AS [Remarks_4_After],
            INSERTED.[#Exec] AS [#Exec_After],
            INSERTED.[Datecreated] AS [Datecreated_After],
            INSERTED.[Operator] AS [Operator_After],
            INSERTED.[LastUpdatedTime] AS [LastUpdatedTime_After],
            0, @Now,
            DELETED.Orig_debt AS [Orig_debt_Before],
            DELETED.Comm_amt AS [Comm_amt_Before],
            INSERTED.Orig_debt AS [Orig_debt_After],
            INSERTED.Comm_amt AS [Comm_amt_After]
        FROM 
            DELETED 
        INNER JOIN 
            INSERTED ON DELETED.Branch@ = INSERTED.Branch@ AND DELETED.Key@ = INSERTED.Key@
        WHERE 
            (INSERTED.PolicyRef@ <> DELETED.PolicyRef@
            OR INSERTED.Poltype <> DELETED.Poltype
            OR INSERTED.Trantype <> DELETED.Trantype
            OR INSERTED.Ledger_dt  <> DELETED.Ledger_dt
            OR INSERTED.Ledger_dt is null and DELETED.Ledger_dt is not null
            OR INSERTED.Ledger_dt is not null and DELETED.Ledger_dt is null
            OR ISNULL(INSERTED.Remarks_4, ''NULL'') <> isnull(DELETED.Remarks_4, ''NULL'')
            OR ISNULL(INSERTED.#Exec, ''NULL'') <> isnull(DELETED.#Exec, ''NULL'')
            OR ISNULL(INSERTED.Operator, ''NULL'') <> isnull(DELETED.Operator, ''NULL'')
            OR INSERTED.Operator <> DELETED.Operator
            OR INSERTED.Orig_debt <> DELETED.Orig_debt
            OR INSERTED.Comm_amt <> DELETED.Comm_amt)
            AND (INSERTED.Trantype <> ''Journal'')
END
GO

CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[Tr_icp_brcledger_Delete] 
ON  [dbo].[icp_brcledger] 
AFTER DELETE
AS 
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO T_FIG_Trigger_Ledger_Delete (Branch@, Key@,PolicyRef@, TranType, PolType)
        SELECT 
            Branch@, Key@,PolicyRef@, Trantype, Poltype
        FROM 
            DELETED
        WHERE 
            (DELETED.Trantype <> ''Journal'')
END
GO
```